# billing in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am supposed to make an app, where people can buy and pay for real goods right inside the app. The app is for a convenience store.

Is there any way to do that? I found some APIs like ZooZ etc., but I read also the Apple guidelines: Apple: 11.3 APPS USING API TO PURCHASE PHYSICAL GOODS OR GOODS AND SERVICES USED OUTSIDE OF THE APPLICATION WILL BE REJECTED.

But there are lot of apps offering the user to purchase and pay for goods via the user's cellphone...

Does anyone know, how to do this the "legal" way?

Comment: Are you sure they are using an API, and not simply going to a website for billing?

Comment: Yes, for example Starbucks Coffee app, you pay from the app

Comment: Doesn't the Starbucks Coffee app just let you scan a barcode which is linked to an account that you have pre-loaded with money. It's the same as swiping your card that you have. You aren't actually PAYING through the app - you don't put your card details in the app and then payment is processed at that point (I could be wrong - I'm in the UK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple guidelines are talking about the In-App Purchase APIs. There is nothing stopping you from selling real goods using another billing API, such as [this one](http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/).

Comment: Yes, you should be fine to. It's the same idea as the eBay or Amazon apps.